# In iOS native App, I need to Apply for Job via LinkedIn

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

I want to give support in my iPhone App for Apply Job via LinkedIn;

First, I will authenticate user via LinkedIn to get access_token; So that user can search any job or company or any other thing; LinkedIn provide APIs for searching jobs and companies etc;

After searching any job, next step is 'Apply for Job'; According to my findings, LinkedIn not providing any way to Apply for Job via any native iPhone app; Yes, there is a plugin present for web apps that supports to **Apply with LinkedIn**; You can integrate that plugin in your own web app but i want it for iPhone App; Can it be possible to use that plugin for iOS App?

Your suggestions will be spotlight for me.

Comment: If they don't support it in the LinkedIn app.. chances are they don't want other people implementing it into their own apps.

Comment: There is also present LinkedIn Own Native App that gives this behavior. So i supposed there should also be any way;

Comment: @RyanG I just confirmed it that LinkedIn not giving this functionality till now; Many thanks